# Allowing the user to change config settings in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

*Using CakePHP 2.6.7*

I have created a plugin and there are 2 variables which for the most part are effectively constants - but the user should be able to change their values (they are paths to header and footer images).

I had been trying to use `Configure::read()` and `Configure::write()` but now realise that isn't what `Configure` is intended for and doesn't actually work in that manner at all.

How should these two variables be stored so that the values can be changed by a user and these changes would be permanent (until they make another change)?

**Initial Solution**

I've now solved the problem by serializing the data in an array to a text file. It would be great if someone had a more elegant solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution would be to store these values in the database as settings and then load them in.

We often do this using a `Setting` model to store the name-value pairs then attach a component (often to `AppController`) that loads in the data. For example, create a component like this:-

```
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');

class SettingsComponent extends Component {

    public function initialize(Controller $Controller) {        
        $Controller->loadModel('Setting');      
        $settings = $Controller->Setting->find('all');      
        foreach($settings as $setting) {            
            Configure::write('Setting.' . $setting['Setting']['name'], $setting['Setting']['value']);           
        }
        return;
    }

}
```

Then load this for any controller that needs these settings:-

```
public $components = array('Settings');
```

You can then access the values in your code like:-

```
Configure::read('Setting.app_name', 'My Cake App');
```

You can easily extend the functionality of the component and what is stored in the `settings` table to make this approach as flexible as you need.

Comment: This is excellent! I'll definitely be making use of this in future projects.